# Population weighted mean in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm working with air pollution data in Google Earth Engine (the JS API). I'm plotting the mean of the raster values over a country (defined by a GeoJSON file), and how it changes over time (it's an ImageCollection with ~100 frames). I know how to plot the unweighted areal mean:

```
print(ui.Chart.image.series(pollution, countryFeature, ee.Reducer.mean(), 10000, 'index'));
```

I also have a raster file with population data. How would I include that to calculate a population-weighted mean of the pollution data over the country instead?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail how you want to weight this mean?

Comment: The idea would be to do a pixelwise multiplication. So if pixels A and B in my pollution raster are in areas that have population densities of eg. 100 and 1,000 people per sqkm, respectively, then pixel B should have 10 times the weight of A when calculating the mean.

Comment: I have come up with my own (inelegant) solution since posting the question, which is to literally multiply the rasters. You then have to calculate the total population in the area of interest and divide the result by that. I was hoping there would be a better solution

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable solution to me.

Comment: Something else to note, if your population layer and data layer have different resolutions, make sure you multiply the population layer by the data layer, i.e. `population.multiply(data)` rather than the other way around.  This will make the resulting layer have the resolution of the `population` layer, which is important if you are dividing by the sum of that `population` layer.